# Meaning of the verb 受ける in the phrase 試験を受ける

Tags: usage

I wonder, how to say just  "**I took the exam**"?

The thing is, that saying **試験【しけん】を受ける 【うける】** could have two meanings, right?
1) The fact, that you took the exam, and 2) success in passing actually.

Am I right? If yes, how should I say "I took an exam", not "I passed an exam" - as f.ex. I am still waiting for results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you are not right, but you came to the right place.

This is about 「受**け**る」 vs. 「受**か**る」.

> 「試験{しけん} + **を** + 受{う}**け**る」

can only mean "to ***take*** the exam".

> 「試験 + **に** + 受**か**る」

can only mean "to ***pass*** the exam".

Those are two different verbs and two different particles.  The past tense versions are:

> 「試験**を**受**けた**。」 (I/Someone **took** the exam.)
>
> 「試験**に**受**かった**。」 (I/Someone **passed** the exam.)

Comment: More generally, 受ける means "to undergo", or "to receive", with a particular passive nuance, which is related to "to take (an exam)". It has several uses, like "罰を受ける", "to receive a punishment".